# Gridview refresh after clicking on linkbutton

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview to show some data from a database.
The cells which are showing the prices are **Style='hidden'**. 
Inside the same column is a Linkbutton which when i press it runs a javascript function **ShowPrice()** to show the price, hides its self and makes visible a second Linkbutton which when i click it runs a javascript function **HidePrice(),** which hides then price, hides its self and makes visible the first LinkButton.
The ShowPrice() function runs and makes the price visible, it hides the Linkbutton and shows the second Linkbutton, but the problem is that hides the second Linkbutton again and shows the first LinkButton.
I thing this has to do something with the postback because the same code runs OK in a plain HTML page.
The code on the page is

```
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblKostos" runat="server" Text='<%#FormatCurrency(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price"), 2)%>' Style="visibility: hidden" CssClass="Gshow"></asp:Label>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="Button4" runat="server"  OnClientClick="ShowPrice()" Text=""> <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" ></span></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="HidePrice()" Text="" Style="visibility: hidden"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ></span></asp:LinkButton>

                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

and the Javascript functions are

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPrice() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Gshow");

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
        }

        var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign");


        for (i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
            x1[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        var x2 = document.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");

        for (i = 0; i < x2.length; i++) {
            x2[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        return true;
    }

    function HidePrice() {

        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Gshow");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign");


        for (i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
            x1[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
        }

        var x2 = document.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");


        for (i = 0; i < x2.length; i++) {
            x2[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

As i told you the code is working on plain HTML 
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any changes made to the DOM with javascript will be lost after a PostBack. So you need to save the state of the buttons somewhere, like a HIddenField. And read those values after PostBack to hide the button again.

Comment: Yes I think this is the problem, the postback. Is there anyway not to postback?